# How can I update a database value when I change the value of a property?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public static class Settings
{
    public static int Trk5 { get; set; }
}

Settings.Trk5 = 2;
db2.Update(new Setting { "Trk5", Value = val.ToString() });
```

Would it be a good idea to somehow combine the updating of the database with the setting of the variable and if so how could I do that?

Can I combine the db2.Update into the set; somehow?

Comment: You should keep in mind that users (of your code) dont expect the code to do anything other than set the property. I have come across way too many properties with business logic in them. In this case, if the update call is slow, setting this might inadverently introduce a performance issue

Comment: I agree with @MatthewEvans. Keeping the storage mechanism separated from the properties makes the logic more flexible. So such hard-coded dependencies should be avoided in the first place. That way, you could also decide to collect multiple property changes and store those changes in one batch, for example. Or in the future you might have to use your Settings logic somewhere else (where you do not have access to your database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let the property save itself in its setter (like @Alsein proposed). You would need to convert your auto-property to a full property for that.

Perhaps this might work:

```
public static class Settings
{
    private static int trk5;

    public static int Trk5
    {
        get { return trk5; }
        set
        {
            if (trk5 != value)
            {
                trk5 = value;
                db2.Update(new Setting { "Trk5", Value = value.ToString() });
            }
        }
    }
}

Settings.Trk5 = 2;
```

However, I doubt if your `db2.Update` call will work this way. You are creating a new `Setting` instance there, but you did not specify the property name for the `"Trk5"` value...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `Update` method within the property.

If you want it to be automatically applied to every single properties, consider the following solutions:

1. [Make a proxy that raises the changing event dynamically at runtime.](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2008/08/04/implement-inotifypropertychanged-with-castledynamicproxy/)
2. [Inserting the notification statically at build time](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged).

Comment: https://github.com/Fody/FodyAddinSamples/tree/master/AutoPropertiesSample